# Send tmux command to tmuxinator

Tags: command, tmux, tmuxinator

Specifically, I need to create a profile that by default will have a small pain displaying the clock, which can be triggered with `C-b t`. However, I couldn't find the way to do that.

In [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/259#issuecomment-65006638), a Collaborator of the project said it could be defined like a regular command, but on my ZSH setup, it just didn't work, saying "zsh: Command not found: C-b".

Does anyone happen to know how I can achieve this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
windows:
  - work:
      panes:
        - tmux clock-mode
        - ipython
```

Below is what happens when typing `tmux clock-mode` inside tmux session:

1. current tmux client connect to tmux server
2. attach to current(or the most recently) session
3. since the `-t` argument is omitted, the currently active pane in the current window is used for the `clock-mode` command.

Checkout the session in `$man tmux` for more detail.

```
COMMANDS
     This section contains a list of the commands supported by tmux.  Most commands accept the optional -t argument with one of target-client, target-session
     target-window, or target-pane.  These specify the client, session, window or pane which a command should affect.  target-client is the name of the pty(7)
     file to which the client is connected, for example either of /dev/ttyp1 or ttyp1 for the client attached to /dev/ttyp1.  If no client is specified, the
     current client is chosen, if possible, or an error is reported.  Clients may be listed with the list-clients command.
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit how this solves the problem?

Comment: This is weird when I saw the command on one pane, and the clock displays on another pane.
[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sfbo5v2j8wp5gte/Screenshot%202015-02-28%2020.44.07.png?dl=0)

Comment: @NgocPham you should explicitly specify your target pane with `tmux clock-mode -t target-pane` as there is no guarantee for the active pane at the bootstrap progress. For the reason that the clock shows up on the first pane in your screenshot, please read https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/52

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly now. All I need is `tmux clock-mode -t session-name:window-name:top-right`. Thank you!